# No response from PHP with JSON request

Tags: javascript, php, json

I'm trying to work through a JSON to PHP and back example but can't figure out why I cannot get a success response to occur when setting dataType to json.  Any help as to what I need to do and where I can find a good tutorial would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

```
  var selected = $('#getID').val();
$.ajax({
    url: 'includes/ajaxCalls.php',
    type: "POST",
    data: {action: 'test', id: selected},
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (results) {
        alert("completed");
    },
    fail: function (data) {
        console.log('Could not get posts, server response');
    }
});
```

PHP

```
if (isset($_POST['action']) && !empty($_POST['action'])) {
   $action = json_decode($_POST['action']);
   switch ($action) {
    case 'test' : test();
        break;
    case 'blah' : blah();
        break;
    default:
        echo "hello";
  }
}
  function test() {
   header("Content-Type: application/json", true);
  $array = array(0,1,2,3);
  echo json_encode($array);
}
```

Comment: What is the current response that you are getting? Please try logging the response from the server (php file)

Comment: Well @tai you are not supposed to use `json_decode` in this `$action = json_decode($_POST['action']);` line. Because the AJAX request is fetched as Array itself so `$_POST['action']` will solve your purpose.

Due to this, your `default:` gets executed in switch which is not providing JSON.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some things you need to fix on your PHP code,

1) You don't have to call json_decode on `$_POST['action']`, you have a string in action variable so you can simply call $_POST['action'], don't have to pass it to json_decode. json_decode is used when the data is a JSON string which is then converted to an array in PHP.

2) Don't set the header in your `test()` you are already requesting for JSON data from your AJAX call, and from your server i.e PHP you are echo-ing JSON back so you don't have to explicitly set the header here.

Change `$action = json_decode($_POST['action']);` TO `$action = $_POST['action'];`

Answer (score 1):

Change `$action = json_decode($_POST['action']);` to  `$action = $_POST['action'];`